# Evopdf - html to pdf 9.0 for .net not working with ES6

Tags: .net, evopdf

I am using latest version 9 of the Evopdf. HTML to PDF Converter v9.0 for .NET - New Edition ( NE )
However my html page URL which has ES6 statements is not getting printed.

Appreciate any inputs if anyone facing same issue.